# Calling scanf_s() with array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, scanf

I tried this code, but it is not working.

```
char word1[40];
printf("Enter text: \n");
scanf_s("%s", word1);
printf("word1 = %s", word1);
```

When I execute it, it shows:

> ```
> word1 =
> ```

Comment: It might sound stupid, but did you enter anything when it prompted?

Comment: If you are working in C++, you should generally prefer to use `std::string` and iostreams for input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully read the [MSDN documentation of `scanf_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx), you'll notice that you have to supply the length of the string buffer:

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size
>   to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string
>   control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is
>   passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to
>   the buffer or variable.

Adjust your `scanf_s()` call as follows:

```
scanf_s("%s", word1, _countof(word1));
```

That should work.

(Note that `_countof()` requires including `<stdlib.h>`.)